# AH00526: BalancerMember Bad syntax for a balancer name

Tags: apache, load-balancing, httpd.conf

I am trying to configure a load balancer using Apache Httpd 2.4.6 on a CentOS 7.3 VM. However, "apachectl configtest" fails with the error message

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 32 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
BalancerMember Bad syntax for a balancer name
```

Although I **have** loaded mod_proxy_http (so http://192.168.56.2:5555 should contain a valid protocol), and the syntax matches those in the examples I've found.

Any ideas on what's wrong? My httpd.conf looks like follows:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 5555
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin my.email@my.domain.com
ServerName center.mcjwi01.eur.ad.sag:5555
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

LogLevel debug

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<Proxy "balancer:iscluster">
    BalancerMember http://192.168.56.2:5555
    BalancerMember http://192.168.56.3:5555
    ProxySet lbmethod=bybusiness
</Proxy>
ProxyPass "/" "balancer:iscluster"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "balancer:iscluster"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, syntax is wrong, correctly it should be:

```
<Proxy balancer://iscluster>
    BalancerMember http://192.168.56.2:5555
    BalancerMember http://192.168.56.3:5555
    ProxySet lbmethod=bybusiness
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://iscluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://iscluster/
```

Note: I removed the " everywhere because afaik they are not really necessary, I also matched trailing slashes to avoid issues with your proxying.

Comment: Thenks very much. If I get it right, my error was not in the BalancerMember statement, but in the name of the balancer? So, I think that the error message is somewhat misleading.

Comment: the error was the missing "://" when you defined the balancer iscluster, just as typical url that include the http https scheme which go with :// same happens with balancer, which is another scheme for apache httpd server, not sure if I explain myself correctly on this.